# How to correctly parse temperature from string in php?

Tags: php, json, parsing

I am trying to show temperature on my website. I have a forecast in json that I get from api and there is this field that I need to get the temperature from:

> "fcttext_metric":"A mainly sunny sky. High near 30 ° C. Winds SE at 10 to 15 km/h."

I tried to parse only float numbers which works well, but it fails when there is more text behind it like in the case above. I tried to show only first 2 chars but when the temperature is negative it fails again. What can I do about this?

```
$str = 'A mainly sunny sky. High near 30 ° C. Winds SE at 10 to 15 km/h.';
$deg = filter_var($str, FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_FLOAT);
$res = substr($deg, 0, 2);
print_r($res);
```

Comment: Do a substring replacement to get rid of the extra characters before you do the conversion.

Comment: But how? Some days the API gives me only 'A mainly sunny sky. High near 30° C.' Sometimes it adds the second sentence behind it. And who knows what else it can add to it. I am not sure if the first sentence can be missing as well. Basically I would somehow have to get the number next to the "°C".

Comment: You are going to have to come up with a regex that finds what you are looking for.  " ° C." is easy to search for if that is consistently in the string.

Comment: Can the api return more than one temperature? I mean : A mainly ... 30° C .... 35 ° C.

Comment: I believe it should not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use this regex. It should match integer values before ° (&deg) sign. Like 30 or -30

```
preg_match('/(\-?\d+)\s*°/', $str, $matches);
echo $matches[1];
```